# Epoxy bar top finish over boiled linseed oil

Tags: finish-selection

I made bar top out of reclaimed redwood (planed and edged to clean wood) which I edged with stained white ash.  I intented to apply bar top epoxy.  I was using boiled linseed oil on other projects and without any thought decided to apply boiled linseed to my top.  Is there any way I can still epoxy this top or should I go with polyurethane?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: As per @NeilN's Answer once the BLO is good and 'dry' there should be no problems. People regularly use epoxy for fills on wood that was previously oiled (I've done it myself many times), without any apparent adhesion problems although that's not quite the same as the adhesion needed for a full film finish. I'm not sure that you need to wait the full month, but it wouldn't hurt!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are good as long as you have let the BLO fully cure/dry.  Which could be up to a month or more depending on how thick it is and the drying conditions.